# Application developer invitation email doesn't allow developer to accept

Tags: google-app-engine

We are trying to add a developer to our application.  We specify the developer's email in the "Invite a user to collaborate on this application" form on the Administration->Permissions page of the admin console of the application and click "invite user".  The invitation email is received by the user but when the link to accept the invitation is clicked they are prompted to create a new application rather than simply participate in the existing one.  The user in question is a Google Apps user just like other user's we've added to the application so we are confused as to why the system is behaving differently for this user and preventing us from adding them as a developer.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In the past when I've had issues I've had some success by removing the developer from the permissions and re-adding them. They should get another invitation, which may work out more favourably. You can also get them to log out of all other google accounts - multiple login can get confused on occasion.

Comment: Thanks Nick, we've certainly tried this a few times to no avail.  Any other suggestions?